# Hacer referencia a una columna de un dataframe de forma dinámica

Tags: r

El problema consiste en hacer referencia a una columna de un dataframe de forma dinámica, en este caso, se tienen varias columnas que son años, de 2010 a 2019, y es necesario hacer cálculos con ellas. Los años (columnas) que se incorporan al dataframe pueden variar y se necesita conocer el primer y último.

Por un lado tenemos este dataframe:

```
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Municipio: chr  "Albacete" "Alicante/Alacant"
 $ 2010     : num  74.1 64
 $ 2011     : num  67.4 58.6
 $ 2012     : num  53 50.1
 $ 2013     : num  60.4 49.5
 $ 2014     : num  63.7 49.4
 $ 2015     : num  71.8 48.6
 $ 2016     : num  63.3 50.8
 $ 2017     : num  66.3 55.5
 $ 2018     : num  69.9 54.7
 $ 2019     : num  79.6 57.8
```

Debería poder hacer algo así:

```
ejercicios <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019")
ejercicion <- min(ejercicios)
ejerciciox <- max(ejercicios)
dfama$Variación <- ((dfama$`ejerciociox` - dfama$`ejercicion`) / dfama$`ejercicion`) * 100
```

En lugar de:

```
dfama$Variación <- ((dfama$'2019' - dfama$'2010') / dfama$'2010') * 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si las columnas siempre se corresponden con un año, lo más sencillo que se me ocurre podría ser:

```
rango <- range(ejercicios)

dfama$Variación <- (dfama[rango[2]] - dfama[rango[1]]) / dfama[rango[1]] * 100
```

`range()` nos retorna el rango es decir el mínimo y el máximo que usamos luego para seleccionar los valores apropiados para el cálculo.

Con respecto a lo que has intentado, esto:

```
dfama$`ejerciociox`
```

No es lo que estás suponiendo, es simplemente la selección de la columna `ejerciciox` que no existe en el `data.frame` por que es una variable externa, la forma correcta eventualmente sería así:

```
dfama[ejerciociox] # Si quieres un data.frame
dfama[,ejerciociox] # Si quieres un vector
```

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, ya que no me percate que cuando respondi, se estaba llamando a las variables de manera incorrecta

Answer (score 1):

podrías definir el vector de ejercicios como los valores numéricos correspondientes a los nombres de tu data frame

```
ejercicios = as.numeric(names(aux)[grepl("[0-9]",names(aux))])
```

con grepl buscas el patron [0-9], es decir las columnas que sean solo numéricas, estas las buscas en los nombres de tu data frame y luego la haces numerica para poder aplicar el min y max.

y ahi ya podrias aplicar lo que decias tú

Donde usando tidyverse puedes hacerlo con la funcion mutate()

```
ejercicion <- min(ejercicios)
ejerciciox <- max(ejercicios)

dfama = dfama %>%
  mutate(nueva_variable = (get(ejerciciox) - get(ejercicion)) / get(ejercicion) * 100)
```

y llamando a cada variable con la función get, ya que son variables externas